# How to Load Partial Views on Radio Button selection?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

I am trying to load different partial views in a single div by depending on radio button selection. when the user clicks on Individual button that partial view should appear, if click on Business then Business Partial view should appear

My view page code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[name=RegesterHere]").on('change', function () {
            var $radio = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRegisterForm", "Home")',
                data: RegesterHere = $radio.val(),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#loadpartial").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<h2>GetRegisterForm</h2>
<table>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegesterHere)</td>
        <td colspan="2">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RegesterHere, "Individual") Individual
                          @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RegesterHere, "Business") Business</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="loadpartial">
</div>
```

and my controller code is

```
[HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult GetRegisterForm(string RegesterHere)
        {
            if (RegesterHere == "Individual")
            {
                return PartialView("IndividualPartialViewName");
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("BusinessPartialViewName");
            }

        }
```

Can someone help me to find the error. When I am running this code its directly showing BusinessPartialName. I am not able to see Parent View Radio Buttons in the output. Without selecting radio button it directly loading second partial view on my page.

Comment: which problem you face ?

Comment: When I am running this code its directly showing BusinessPartialName. I am not able to see Parent View Radio Buttons in the output. Without selecting radio button it directly loading second partial view on my page.

Comment: lets try with below will work

Comment: make your else an `else if(RegesterHere == "Business")`. Does RegesterHere has a default value? another thing to try is to make RegesterHere in you Model nullable i.e `public string RegesterHere? {get;set;}`. and one minor thing, please correct the spelling mistake. it should be `RegisterHere`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load Different partial views on radio button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017314/load-different-partial-views-on-radio-button-click)

Answer (score 2):

Lets try with below AJAX Call .

```
 var radiobuttonval = $radio.val();

 var isselect = $("input:radio[name=RegesterHere]:checked").val();
             if(isselect !="" || isselect !=undefined){
                 $.get("@Url.Action("GetRegisterForm", "Home")", {RegesterHere : radiobuttonval  }, function (data) {
                        $("#loadpartial").html("");
                        $("#loadpartial").html(data);
                    });


                   }
```

Comment: you have to check your radio button is selected or not.Otherwise Ajax call would be call